# Custom info window, google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

i have an app which it will display some locations on the map from a database . Everything is working fine but i wan't to display a rating bar in my custom info window . I have tried some tutorials but the problem is i get my data from JSON , using php .It works but the rating bar is by default the last , retrieved information from the database .

This is my class , implementing the `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter`

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

private Activity context;
private int rating;
private RatingBar RTB;

public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(Activity context,int rating){
    this.context = context;
    this.rating=rating;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customwindow, null);
    RTB = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.mark_rating);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);
    RTB.setRating(rating);
    tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
    tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());
    return view;
}
```

And this where i add the markers

```
for(int i=0 ; i<response.length();i++){
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
    String name = person.getString("nom");
    String long_i = person.getString("longitude");
    String lat_i = person.getString("latitude");
    int  rating = person.getInt("rating");
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat_i) , Double.parseDouble(long_i)))
        .title(name)
        .snippet("Nothing")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("doctor_icon",85,85))));
    CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this,rating);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(23.6850,90.3563), 6.0f));
}
```

And for the layout file , I have 2 textview and 1 ratingBar

[image: Nothing]

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing with custom info window ?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** You can not set any thing else `BitmapDescriptor` on marker

**Solution** This is way to convert any xml layout to bitmap. You can make your layout to bitmap.

**Here is magic**

```
BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(bitmap));
marker.setIcon(icon);
```

and

```
 private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(@Nullable Bitmap loadedImage) {
        View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.layout_marker_view, null);
        ImageView markerImageView = customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.civProfile);
        if (loadedImage != null)
            markerImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
        customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
        if (drawable != null)
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

and `layout_marker_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_marker_view"
              android:layout_width="70dp"
              android:layout_height="70dp"
              android:background="@drawable/ic_marker_blue"
              android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <com.baselib.view.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civProfile"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you , but i think you didn't understood my question . All i wan't is retrieve the rating for every user from the database and add it to the rating bar . As you can see in the picture it gets the last rating and set it to all of the ratikg bars

Comment: Still i did not get you, do you want  a touchable rating bar?

Comment: Noo not at all . as you can see in the screen i already have the ratingbar in the custom info window but the problem is .it displays the same rating to all the markers .

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass the rating in the adapter, just set the adapter once. Also, position the camera once, as in loop it has the same effect. And for individual rating for each person, associate objects with markers using setTag(), so it goes like:

```
CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity.this);
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(23.6850,90.3563), 6.0f));

// associate objects with markers

for(int i=0 ; i<response.length();i++){
    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
    String name = person.getString("nom");
    String long_i = person.getString("longitude");
    String lat_i = person.getString("latitude");

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat_i) , Double.parseDouble(long_i)))
        .title(name)
        .snippet("Nothing")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromBitmap(resizeMapIcons("doctor_icon",85,85)))).setTag(person);
}
```

And in your adapter, do this to set rating in getInfoContents() :

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customwindow, null);
    RTB = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.mark_rating);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView tvSubTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle);
    tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
    tvSubTitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    // get json object associated with it:

    JSONObject person = (JSONObject) marker.getTag();

    // get rating:

    int  rating = person.getInt("rating");

    // set it

    if (rating!= null){
        RTB.setRating(rating)
    }

    return view;
}
```